# Why does my Meteor method 404

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a method defined in server/methods/methods.js:

```
Meteor.methods({
  'createRole': function(name) {
    if (this.connection && !Roles.userIsInRole(this.userId, 'manage-users')) {
      throw new Meteor.Error('Not authorized to create user roles');
    } else if (!Meteor.roles.find({name: name}).count()) {
      Roles.createRole(name);
      var admins = Meteor.users.find({ emails: { $elemMatch: { address: { $in: _.pluck(Meteor.settings.admins, 'email')}}}}).fetch();
      return Roles.addUsersToRoles(admins, name);
    }
  },
```

I call the method in server/config/roles.js:

```
var roles = [
    'manage-users',
    'schedule-any',
    'edit-any',
    'delete-any',
    'manage-settings',
    'schedule-own',
    'edit-own',
    'delete-own'
  ];

// Creates any roles in the list that don't exist
roles.forEach(function(role) {
  if (!Meteor.roles.find({name: role}).count()) {
    Meteor.call('createRole', role);
  }
});
```

This results in a 404 with the following stack trace:

```
W20150426-12:19:18.264(-4)? (STDERR) Error: Method not found [404]
W20150426-12:19:18.264(-4)? (STDERR)   at [object Object]._.extend.apply (/private/var/folders/21/_h470ps14cn22051frhwhrfr0000gn/T/meteor-test-runsw86fl/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/ddp.js:2330:19)
W20150426-12:19:18.264(-4)? (STDERR)   at [object Object]._.extend.call (/private/var/folders/21/_h470ps14cn22051frhwhrfr0000gn/T/meteor-test-runsw86fl/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/ddp.js:2300:17)
W20150426-12:19:18.264(-4)? (STDERR)   at Accounts.onCreateUser.email (app/server/config/roles.js:17:12)
W20150426-12:19:18.264(-4)? (STDERR)   at Array.forEach (native)
W20150426-12:19:18.264(-4)? (STDERR)   at app/server/config/roles.js:15:7
W20150426-12:19:18.265(-4)? (STDERR)   at app/server/config/roles.js:42:3
W20150426-12:19:18.265(-4)? (STDERR)   at /private/var/folders/21/_h470ps14cn22051frhwhrfr0000gn/T/meteor-test-runsw86fl/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:222:10
W20150426-12:19:18.265(-4)? (STDERR)   at Array.forEach (native)
W20150426-12:19:18.265(-4)? (STDERR)   at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/raddevon/.meteor/packages/velocity_meteor-tool/.1.1.3_2.mgkc7d++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20150426-12:19:18.266(-4)? (STDERR)   at /private/var/folders/21/_h470ps14cn22051frhwhrfr0000gn/T/meteor-test-runsw86fl/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:117:5
W20150426-12:19:18.266(-4)? (STDERR)
=> Exited with code: 8
```

Why am I unable to call this method? I am able to call other methods in server/startup/startup.js, so I'm confused why I'm unable to call this particular method here.

Comment: Is the code in `roles.js` run as soon as the file is evaluated, or is is part of a callback?

Comment: @DavidWeldon It's not in a callback. I should be running as the file is evaluated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`server/config/roles.js` is evaluated before `server/methods/methods.js` (they have the same level of nesting and 'config' is alphabetically before 'methods'), therefore, the method is not defined at the time of the call. A simple solution is just to call the method in a `Meteor.startup` callback:

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
  roles.forEach(function(role) {
    if (!Meteor.roles.find({name: role}).count()) {
      Meteor.call('createRole', role);
    }
  });
});
```

This will ensure all files have been evaluated prior to executing the `roles` code. Alternative solutions include moving your method definition inside of a `lib` directory or adding it to a package.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run it in Meteor.startup

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
    roles.forEach(function(role) {
        if (!Meteor.roles.find({name: role}).count()) {
            Meteor.call('createRole', role);
        }
    });
});
```